# Codeigniter libraries - Error loading custom classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to load my custom class which **doesnot** extend from any core class.
I have placed my custom class in a subfolder inside application/libraries.

So here is my folder structure

```
application
    |_ libraries
      |_ cgh
          |_ cgh_asset.php
          |_ cgh_article.php
          |_ cgh_asettype.php
    |_ controllers
      |_ welcome.php
```

Class Cgh_article is a subclass of Cgh_asset

Cgh_asset.php :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
abstract class Cgh_asset
{
    public $id;
    public $type;
    public $title;
    public $content;
    public $user;

    abstract public function generate_url();
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->generate_url();
    }
}

?>
```

Cgh_article.php :

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Cgh_article extends Cgh_asset
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->type=Cgh_assettype::article;
    }
    function generate_url()
    {
        $this->url="Article_URL";
    }
}


?>
```

Cgh_assettype.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Cgh_assettype
{
    const type1="type1";
    const type2="type2";
    const article="article";
}

?>
```

Controller welcome.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('cgh/Cgh_assettype','cgh/Cgh_asset','cgh/Cgh_article');

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

The error I get is :
Unable to load the requested class: Cgh_assettype

I must have tried all possible upper and lower case combinations of classnames, filenames, but the error is always the same.

---

After going through some answers, I think probably I should add one basic question here - Is it at all possible to have my own custom object types within codeigniter ... types that should be quite obvious from my question ?

---

This seems to work for me, so here is what I will be doing ... at least till something breaks :

In the constructor of my controller, I use require_once for my classes ... and good thing is I can combine all my classes into a single file -- my classes initially were in a single file anyways --This is my controller after the changes, and this works :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public $cgh_assettype;
    public $cgh_asset;
    public $cgh_article;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->library(array('cgh/cgh_assettype','cgh/cgh_asset','cgh/cgh_article'));
        echo "Including CGH<br />";
        echo "<p>Apppath is ". APPPATH. "</p>";
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/cgh/Cgh_assettype.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/cgh/Cgh_asset.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/cgh/Cgh_article.php');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $iCgh_article=new Cgh_article();
        echo "<p>$iCgh_article->url</p>";
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried lowercasing filenames and loading **an array** of libraries; `$this->load->library(array('cgh/cgh_assettype','cgh/cgh_asset','cgh/cgh_article'));`?

Comment: I've tried all possible combinations of lower and uppercase versions of classnames, filenames. Doesnt work. I've tried removing the Cgh_ prefix from classnames, filenames. Doesnt work. I've tried moving my class files into the root of application/libraries. Doesnt work. Currently I am trying                                                      require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/cgh/Cgh_assettype.php'); in index.php

Comment: Btw you are trying to load `cgh_assettype` but your file is named as `cgh_asettype.php`, did you check that?

Comment: I wish that was the case Burak ! The folder structure in this question was simply typed in by me, and that was a typo... But many thanks for the tip ... I re-checked all filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`$this->load->library`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) for each library.

```
$this->load->library('cgh/Cgh_assettype');
$this->load->library('cgh/Cgh_asset');
$this->load->library('cgh/Cgh_article');
```

[`$this->load->library`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) takes 3 parameters.

1. File to load
2. (optional) `$config` array
3. (optional) String to rename library to (`$this->Renamed_library`)

If you want to load multiple libraries on one line, use an array as the 1st parameter.

```
$this->load->library(array('cgh/Cgh_assettype','cgh/Cgh_asset','cgh/Cgh_article'));
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket. But I tried that, dint work. Even if I load only one of the classes, say $this->load->library('cgh/Cgh_assettype');
it gives an error for Cgh_assettype

Comment: Maybe CodeIgniter doesn't like the `Cgh_` prefix?  Try removing that.

Comment: Unfortunately, that dint work either. Another thing I tried is moving these class files from the cgh folder to the root of libraries. Still the error remains...

Answer (score 1):

Are you library file names capitalized? (Your submitted folder structure says they are not).

I don't know about having libraries within sub-directories, but I know the file names need to be capitalized.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Naming Conventions

- File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php
- Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
- Class names and file names must match.

Answer (score 0):

You should load library or whatever only once. If you're loading for second time, you get that error.